# MySql execution timeout

Tags: mysql, timeout, execution

I have a local LAMP server on my machine with phpmyadmin also installed. 
I am trying to run a Levenstein distance calculator between expressions with known spelling and ones with possible spelling errors. The 300K misspelled stack is being checked against 1.5M correct ones. The program runs fine and does what it has to do but stops at 60 seconds.

I did try to change the execution time as:

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=20000;
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=20000;
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800
```

with no improvement. The I changed the php.ini as:

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
```

and restarted the server. Still no change.

Can somebody advise me how I can have the script run for a couple of hours on my local machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was the php that timed out. I added the following to my script:

```
set_time_limit(3000);
```

and now it runs for as long as I want it to. :)